# If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, how to proof $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are also independent

Tags: independence

this is Probability Density Function(pdf)
if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, how to prove $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are also independent

Answer (score 2):

That $X$ and $Y$ are independent just means that the sigma algebras they generate are independent. But the sigma algebra $X^2$ generates is containedin the sigma algebra generates by $X$ and the same goes for $Y^2$.

Comment: Can you express it in a functional way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, if you are not familiar with measure theory. I assume we are talking about real-valued random variables. 
Let $a,b\geq0$
$$P(X^2 \leq a,\,Y^2 \leq b)=P(-\sqrt{a}\leq X \leq \sqrt{a},\,-\sqrt{b}\leq Y \leq \sqrt{b}) \\= P(-\sqrt{a}\leq X \leq \sqrt{a})P(-\sqrt{b}\leq Y \leq \sqrt{b})=P(X^2 \leq a)P(Y^2 \leq b),$$
where we have used the independence of $X,Y$  at the beginning of the second line. If $a<0$ or $b<0$, then 
$$P(X^2 \leq a,\,Y^2 \leq b)=0=P(X^2 \leq a)P(Y^2 \leq b).$$
Hence, $X^2,Y^2$ are independent.

Comment: Thank you. is it pmf( probability mass function) right?